# Transferring Data with LabView with LAN connection

Tags: lan, labview

A LabView program is reading a picture and it does some calculation with data from a voltmeter. 

But I want to send this result of the calculation over a LAN Connection to another PC so that PC does some other calculations with that result.
 I know that I can do those calculations on the same PC but it is about the principle to send data to another PC fully automatic. So the user won't have to do anything to send the data to the other PC (and with anything I mean like filling a IP or something like that for the PC).

It might sound a bit weird but if you want more information about this project please tell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the LabVIEW examples is a server/client example (search for 'server'). The user would start both programs on the two computers. First they need to find each other, that could be done via UDP as a broadcast from the client, the server would respond to this UDP broadcast with a reply via TCP (it gets the clients address with the UDP details). On the client a TCP listener to which the server connects and the data is transfered.